# Python 3.x How to convert and process bytes to list (that also has a dict)?

Tags: python, byte

I am playing with a product API that returns data as bytes containing the list and dictionary I need.

If I convert it to utf-8, it becomes a big string.  I suppose I could convert that back to a list, but there has to be a better way.  I am new to python and very new to bytes objects.

Below is a sample - my fitbit data.  First line is just the output from `type()`

```
<class 'bytes'>
[{
  "ActivityDate": "2018-07-02T00:00:00",
  "TotalDistance": 2.0099999904632568,
  "TrackerDistance": 2.0099999904632568,
  "LoggedActivitiesDistance": 0.0,
  "VeryActiveDistance": 0.0
}]
```

Just looking to interact with this as a normal iterable list. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: So the API is sending you JSON? Is that it?

Comment: `json.loads(yourdata)`, or `response.json()` if you are using `requests` to make the API call.

Comment: How is anything there the output from `type()`? The `type` function either takes 1 argument and gives you the type of that, or takes 3 arguments and gives you a new class object; it never gives you a list with a dict in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json.loads()` to convert your string into a dictionary of strings and values. Also, you may want to `str(result)` to convert your data into a string beforehand:

```
import json
data = json.loads( str( result ))
```